# vertically aligned images using split without remaining sticky above the content

Tags: html, css, class, split, grid

I'm trying to keep the images with text at the top of the page. But when I scroll down the page, the images go up and I get to see the following section. I want to scroll down the page without having a sticky section floating and the contents in the back or front. I tried to adjust the position but I couldn't fix the issue.

Thank you in advance

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .split {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .left {
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .right {
    right: 0;
  }
  
  
  .centered img {
    width: 150px;
  }
  

  
  .text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    color: white;
  
  }

p { 
  color: #000000; 
}
```

```html
<!-- Hogarth Luna Test - Version 3 -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Luna - The exploration of the moon - Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/NewStyle.css" />
</head>

<body class='home'>
    <section class="hero hero-unit-moon-exploration">

    <div class="split left">
  
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642150787688-3f1db7d0cd37?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="text-block">
          <h4>Nature</h4>
        </div>

        
      </div>
      
      <div class="split right">
        
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638913662380-9799def8ffb1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw2fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="text-block">
          <h4>Nature</h4>
        </div>

        
      </div>
           
    </section>




    

    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p><p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p><p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p><p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
   
        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually, for me the images always stay at the top, both in your snippet here as when I run your code. So not sure what your issue is? Or *is* that the issue? You want them not to be sticky? Then you should change the position to absolute instead of fixed.

Comment: When I switch the position to [fixed], the text goes behind the images. I don't want the text behind or front. I want it to remain under the images. So when I scroll down, the images would go up and I see the text below.

Comment: That's why you need `absolute` and not `fixed`. Then make sure your next section only starts relatively to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of having 2 images in your hero section, you're probably better off using `grid`. It also simplifies your code a lot.

```css
body {
font-family: Arial;
color: white;
}

.hero {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.split {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.centered img {
width: 150px;
}

.text-block {
position: absolute;
color: white;
bottom: 50%;
right: 50%;
}

.paragraphs {
position: relative;
}

p {
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Hogarth Luna Test - Version 3 -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Luna - The exploration of the moon - Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body class='home'>
<section class="hero hero-unit-moon-exploration">
    <div class="split left">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1642150787688-3f1db7d0cd37?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638913662380-9799def8ffb1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw2fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="paragraphs">
    <p>
        The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.The number of lines in a paragraph depends on the size of the browser window. If you resize the browser window, the number of lines in this paragraph will change.
    </p>
</div>        
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried the grid but when I added the images; they were aligned on top of each other. I tried using a flex, but I didn't get the result I was looking for. The only thing I didn't try was tables. But Anyway, I'm glad the problem was solved and Thank you so much for your help.